# How to upgrade using terminal

Tags: command-line, upgrade

How can i upgrade my existing ubuntu 12.04 to 13.04 using terminal... please help me with the procedure. I am having problem regarding upgrade.

Comment: What problem specifically?

Answer (score 5):

Using this: `sudo do-release-upgrade`